# Build simple map to my game c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, coordinates, picturebox

I have simple car game and I want to build a simple map with coordinates of car 
I start with pictureBox with my map and point on pictureBox as coordinates of car but it is not easy to determine the point. Is there a better way?

Comment: Please post a code sample.  "Is there a better way" is impossible to answer if we don't know what you're currently doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would probably be better answered at the game development section of stackoverflow.

That being said, you'll need a simple function to convert your "world" coordinates to your "map" coordinates.

If you have a 800px by 800px "world" screen and a 80px by 80px "map" screen, then every 10 pixels on your "world" screen is represented by a single pixel on your "map" screen.

In simple pseudocode:

```
carCoordOnMap.x = carWorldPosition.x / (world_screen_width / map_screen_width);
carCoordOnMap.y = carWorldPosition.y / (world_screen_height / map_screen_height);
```

Now take that car coordinate position, and use it to draw a point on your map.

Note that this will work for a fixed 2d map where pixels correspond to position. If you have a moving map or a 3d map, you'll have to do a big more massaging of the position data.